# Dupes of SO questions?

Tags: discussion, policy

What should we do about dupes of SO questions tagged with `latex`? Link to original question? C/P the answer from over there?

Comment: See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1/importing-questions-from-so for an earlier discussion on this.

Comment: Since this question concerns crossposts rather than the intention to import already existing SO posts, I would like to continue the discussion with an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. I recommend giving a
   profound and satisfying answer to
   the question on *this* site. This
   might be sufficient to convince the
   questioner to come back here for TeX
   related questions.
2. A link to the question on
   SO should be provided, for
   transparency and to avoid redundant
   effort.

Comment: Agree completely.